# Error in working with useEffect for fetching data from an API

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, axios, expo, use-effect

I am learning React Native, and in following one of the live-coding sessions on YouTube I have come across the following problem.
What I want to do is: I am making an app with expo and I want to fetch data from [CoinGecko's free crypto API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation). My code is:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
```

```js
const getCoinData = async (coinId) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinId}?community_data=false&developer_data=false`
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```js
const BugScreen = () => {
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCoinData = async () => {
      const fetchedCoinData = await getCoinData("bitcoin");
      setCoin(fetchedCoinData);
    };
    fetchCoinData();
  }, []);

  const {
    name,
    symbol,
    image: { small },
    market_cap_rank,
  } = coin;

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <Text>{symbol}</Text>
      <Image source={{ uri: small }} style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }} />
      <Text>{market_cap_rank}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default BugScreen;
```

I get an error telling me **null is not an object (evaluating `'coin.name'`)**. I have also included a [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMWQO.png).

The way I understand it each time that the screen is rendered the `useEffect()` should run, and fetch the data, but the strange thing is that even when I add a 'console.log(coin) `in the body of the 'fetchCoinData` function, nothing is written on the console's screen.

It would be so kind of you if you could help me understand what's going wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialise `coin` to be `null` so until the API call resolves, it remains `null`.

Perhaps a better option would be to initialise it to a placeholder object

```js
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  symbol: "",
  image: {
    small: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
  },
  market_cap_rank: ""
}

const BugScreen = () => {
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState({...initialState});

  // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. Based on the [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)'s comment I did the following and it worked:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const getCoinData = async (coinId) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinId}?community_data=false&developer_data=false`
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const BugScreen = () => {
  const initialState = {
    name: "",
    symbol: "",
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    marketCapRank: "",
  };
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCoinData = async () => {
      const fetchedCoinData = await getCoinData("bitcoin");
      const fetchedData = {
        name: fetchedCoinData.name,
        symbol: fetchedCoinData.symbol,
        image: fetchedCoinData.image.small,
        marketCapRank: fetchedCoinData.market_cap_rank,
      };
      setCoin((coin) => {
        return { ...coin, ...fetchedData };
      });
    };
    console.log(coin);
    fetchCoinData();
  }, []);

  const { name, symbol, image, marketCapRank } = coin;

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{name}</Text>
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{symbol}</Text>
      <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ height: 25, width: 25 }} />
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{marketCapRank}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default BugScreen;
```